# Will jQuery search for the ID before filtering other parameters in the selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question is related to performance.

If I use a selector like the following

```
$('#myID a') // Does this find #myID and filter by a?
```

Or should I write the statement like this?

```
$('#myID').find('a')
```

I'm not sure if jQuery is smart enough to execute this statement using the ID first or if it operates exactly like CSS and reads right to left. It's not such a big deal using tags but when you run something like

```
$('#myID .myClass')
```

It makes a HUGE difference in performance.

Comment: What it looks like in your examples is that you want to find all elements then filter based on the ID. `$('a#myID)` would be the way I would do that. It will select the anchor tag that has the ID of myID. Typing it as `$('#myID a')` would actually select all anchor tags that are children of myID.

Comment: True, I omitted the .children() on accident. It's meant to grab the parent element by id and THEN filter the children looking for an anchor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a NetTuts article: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-think-right-to-left-with-jquery/

> As an example, if Sizzle comes across a selector like $('#box p'),
>   it’s true that it works right-to-left, but there’s also a quick regex
>   optimization that will first determine whether the first section of
>   the selector is an id. If so, it’ll use that as the context, when
>   searching for the paragraph tags.

Relevant comment from [SizzleJS](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L87):

```
// Take a shortcut and set the context if the root selector is an ID
// (but not if it'll be faster if the inner selector is an ID)
```

Answer (score 3):

When an Id is in the selector. jQuery will first execute `document.getElementById` then begin filtering for child elements.

basically this is why it is never a great idea to use just attribute or class selectors `$('.someclass') or $('[name=myname]')` without being more specific.  Because it causes the code to traverse the DOM and look at every element to find that class.

By just adding a tagname to the same selector `$('div.someclass') or $('div.[name=myname]')` you improve efficiency becuase it will first run.  `document.getElementsByTagName` narrowing the number of elements to search.