# Comparing the performance of $("#foo .bar") and $(".bar", "#foo")

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, browser

## Scroll down for the `getById.getByClassName` vs. `qSA` comparison!

---

If we wanted to select all elements of class `"bar"` which are inside the element with the ID `"foo"`, we could write this:

```
$( '#foo .bar' )
```

or this:

```
$( '.bar', '#foo' )
```

There are of course other methods to achieve this, but for the sake of this question, let's compare only these two methods.

So, which of the above methods performs better? (Which needs less time to execute?)

I have written this performance test:

```
(function() {
    var i;
    
    console.time('test1');
    for( i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
        $('#question-mini-list .tags');
    }
    console.timeEnd('test1');
    
    console.time('test2');
    for( i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
        $('.tags', '#question-mini-list');
    }
    console.timeEnd('test2');
})();
```

You have to execute it from within the console on the **Stack Overflow start-page**. My results are:

Firefox:
test1: ~90ms
test2: ~18ms

Chrome:
test1: ~65ms
test2: ~30ms

Opera:
test1: ~50ms
test2: ~100ms

So in Firefox and Chrome, the second method is multiple times faster - just as I expected. However, in Opera the situation is reversed. I wonder what's going on here.

Could you please run the test on your machine and explain why Opera performs differently?

---

## Update

I've written this test, in order to investigate whether Opera's qSA really is super-fast. As it turns out, it is.

```
(function() {
    var i, limit = 5000, test1 = 'test1', test2 = 'test2';

    console.time( test1 );
    for( i = 0; i < limit; i += 1 ) {
        document.getElementById( 'question-mini-list' ).getElementsByClassName( 'tags' );
    }
    console.timeEnd( test1 );

    console.time( test2 );
    for( i = 0; i < limit; i += 1 ) {
        document.querySelectorAll( '#question-mini-list .tags' );
    }
    console.timeEnd( test2 );
})();
```

Again, you have to run this code from within the console on the Stack Overflow start-page. I used the Firebug Lite bookmarklet for IE9 (since that browser doesn't implement `console.time`).

So, I compared this method:

```
document.getelementById( 'A' ).getElementsByClassName( 'B' );
```

to this method:

```
document.querySelectorAll( '#A .B' );
```

I've executed the above script five consecutive times in each browser. The arithmetic means are:

[image]

(All numbers are in milliseconds.)

So, the performance of the first method is pretty much the same in the tested browsers (16-36ms). However, while qSA is much slower compared to the first method, in Opera it actually is faster!

So, qSA optimization is possible, I wonder what the other browsers are waiting for...

Comment: `test1: 73ms`, `test2: 11ms`. Opera is an odd browser, I'm not sure why it lags.

Comment: @Blender Please increase the loop limit. My laptop is really slow, so I went with 100. Try 1000. (Results smaller than `4ms` are not reliable...)

Comment: Have you considered including `document.getElementById('foo').getElementsByClassName('bar')` for completeness?

Comment: Different implementations have different optimizations. Whacha gonna do? ;)

Comment: For the testing http://jsperf.com/ will be a better choice.

Comment: @RobG That one is just super-fast. However, for this question, my intent is to compare the above two methods, and not to compare jQuery with native methods.

Comment: For completeness, you should also add tests for: `$('#foo).find('.bar')`.

Comment: @jfriend00 That one is almost identical to my second method (only slightly faster), so I consider them the same...

Comment: Here's a jsperf (a much more refined test tool) with three test case built in: http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-variations.  You can run it in your own browsers.

Comment: @Blender That result is in Opera?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas—don't try qSA then, it's about 3 times faster in IE 8.

Comment: They may be conceptually the same, but they aren't identical in implementation.  There are small differences in the jsperf in some places.

Comment: @jfriend00 jQuery transforms `$('.bar', '#foo')` into `$('#foo').find('.bar')` internally - [see here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core.js#L168). They are the same method. The prior can be considered sugar for the latter.

Comment: I know that, but they don't execute in perfectly identical times because there's apparently a little overhead to transform one to the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery/Sizzle will avoid using the JavaScript based Sizzle engine if the browser supports `querySelectorAll`, and if you pass a valid selector (no custom, non-CSS selectors).

This means that you're ultimately comparing implementations of `querySelectorAll`, assuming you're testing browsers that support it.

There are other optimizations that jQuery or Sizzle uses, so it's tricky when comparing different types of DOM selection in different browsers.

The reason for Opera's performance result seems to be that they have a very highly optimized `querySelectorAll` implementation. `qSA`, being a relatively new method, hasn't been quite as optimized in some browsers compared to older methods like `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: Well, qSA is not that new. It's in Chrome since forever, in Firefox since 3.5, and in IE since 8. The browsers had plenty of time to optimize it. Shame on them (check out my new test above).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Yes, new only relative to some other methods. But you're right. Seems to me that they've had plenty of time to optimize. I'm sure they'll come around eventually.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I'm going to throw another possibility out there. Since your test doesn't do anything with the result, I wonder if the optimization is to not bother with the DOM selection at all. Perhaps it calls the method, but abandons the search. This may explain why the first test takes longer (two function calls). This is pure speculation of course.

Comment: @ЖΞЖ I can confirm that Opera does the query. I've tested both queries "in practice" - see the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/hfNTK/1/ If you execute the last part in Opera, you will see that the tags do get a blue background, and that the execution is super-fast...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Hmmm... but the timed part of your test doesn't use the result of the selection, and there aren't any elements on the page. Did you paste the correct link?

Comment: @ЖΞЖ You have to take the last section of the jsFiddle link (the last 3 lines) and execute it in Opera on the Stack Overflow start page. You will see that the tags turn blue and it executes fast.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Oh, I meant that the optimization may be that the timed code is analyzed and observed that the result is not used. I'm certain that the DOM selection works. I just wondered if perhaps Opera optimized it away when you do a selection and you don't use (or cache) the result. Not a big deal, was just speculating.

Answer (score 1):

And the winner is....

**test 3** `$('#question-mini-list').find('.tags');`

- test1: 25ms
- test2: 19ms
- test3: 10ms

The two methods you suggested are not equivalent.

**test 1**: Sizzle parses from right to left (don't ask it to search ever element on the page, then restrict to an ID).

**test 2**: Using a string as a context is generally of no use, use elements as a context.

**test 3**: Finding elements with an id is blazingly fast. Once you're there it's a breeze to focus in on an item of a given class.

Comment: "*Sizzle parses from right to left*" - I would love a source for that.

Comment: Sizzle has an optimization that if the string starts with an id selector, [it uses that first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7757744/will-jquery-search-for-the-id-before-filtering-other-parameters-in-the-selector/7757792#7757792), so they should be equivalent.

Comment: jQuery transforms `$('.bar', '#foo')` into `$('#foo').find('.bar')` internally. I consider them to be equivalent. The latter is slightly faster of course.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: [Click here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/about-selectors-right-to-left) and see the second to last comment. I've also heard Resig talk about this in a video. I'll see if I can find it again.

Comment: @ЖΞЖ That is nice, but it's not reflected by my results. If Sizzle really did that, then `$( '#foo .bar' )` and `$( '.bar', '#foo' )` would pretty much perform the same..

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Not really. When you do `$('#foo .bar')` in a browser that supports `querySelectorAll`, you're not using Sizzle at all. So it will vary by the browser's implementation of `qSA`. When you do `$( '.bar', '#foo' )`, I'm pretty sure it will be optimized for a `getElementById` followed by a `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: ...also, even without `qSA`, `$( '.bar', '#foo' )` would force a left to right evaluation because you're really doing `$('#foo').find('.bar')`, where it first finds `#foo` then all nested `.bar`s.

Comment: @ЖΞЖ You just answered the question. Opera's qSA is apparently super-optimized, and that's why `$('#foo .bar')` is faster then `$('.bar', '#foo')` in Opera. If you want, post this as an answer and I'll accept it... (tomorrow... have to sleep now...)

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Alright, I'll do that. By the way, I *think* [this is the video](http://ejohn.org/blog/building-a-javascript-library/) where Resig mentions r-to-l evaluation. I may be wrong though. It's been a while.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas am I missing the part where something is faster than $('#question-mini-list').find('.tags'); ? Or somewhere where someone refuted anything I said? Yes, sizzle has some wonderful optimizations, and this could be a very esoteric topic of discussion, but the fact remains: target Ids -> drill down. End of story. You can sometimes get close to this method's speed if you happen upon a built-in exception, but no rule-of-thumb works better. You were looking for the best "all-jquery method of tagetting", here it is.

Comment: I think ŠimeVidas was wondering why that *ID -> sub-dom query* approach was actually slower in Opera. I agree with your overall assessment, so +1 from me.

Comment: @Sinetheta The question is not the best way of selecting, but why the behavior is different in Opera vs other browsers.

Comment: @Dennis fair enough, I guess I lost sight of that when I logged back on to a flurry of R to L discussion in the comments.

Comment: @Sinetheta If the other browsers optimize qSA, and I expect them to, then targeting ID's will actually be slower across browsers. We'll see what the future brings....

Answer (score 1):

For reference, this is 30x faster:

```
document.getElementById("foo").getElementsByClassName("bar");
```

See jsPerf: http://jsperf.com/jquery-selector-variations/3.  This would need a shim to work in older versions of IE.

While jQuery is extremely useful, if speed is of the utmost, it's not always the best tool for the job.

Comment: That "Plain JS" bar ruined the chart `:P`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - Yeah, I noticed that too.  I didn't expect such a dramatic difference.  You can go back to the previous version if you want just those.  Kind of goes to show how much overhead, there can be in both parsing a general purpose selector and in jQuery objects in general.