# What is differences between jquery $("button","#container") and $("#container button") and similar usages?

Tags: jquery

What is the differences between event assign styles?
For example :

```
$("button","#container").click(function(){
    console.log("Usage 1");
});

$("#container").click("button",function(){
    console.log("Usage 2");
});

$("#container button").click(function(){
    console.log("Usage 3");
});

$(document).click("#container button",function(){
    console.log("Usage 4");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mesuutt/8Dkcc/2/

Comment: See here: [Comparing the performance of $(“#foo .bar”) and $(“.bar”, “#foo”)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598759/comparing-the-performance-of-foo-bar-and-bar-foo)

Comment: You have the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598759/comparing-the-performance-of-foo-bar-and-bar-foo

as rightly said by Vidas.

Comment: I'm surprised that statements 2 and 4 work. The API doesn't mention passing a selector into `click()`...

Answer (score 1):

```
$("button","#container").click(function(){
    console.log("Usage 1");
});
```

This will look for `button` element inside `#container` and attach a `click` event handler on each of the `button` element it finds.

```
$("#container").click("button",function(){
    console.log("Usage 2");
});
```

This will attach `click` event handler on `#container` and pass "button" string as event data to `click` event handler.

```
$("#container button").click(function(){
    console.log("Usage 3");
});
```

This will work same as your first code snippet.

```
$(document).click("#container button",function(){
    console.log("Usage 4");
});
```

This will attach `click` event handler on the whole `document` and pass "#container button" string as event data to `click` event handler.

Answer (score 0):

The statements 2 and 4 are not specified by the jQuery Documentation, so we can forget about them. As for statements 1 and 3, they bind the click handlers to the individual buttons - they both achieve the same thing.

My recommendation would be to make use of event delegation:

```
$( container ).on( 'click', 'button', function () { ... });
```

where `container` is a reference to the `#container` element. (You want to get the references to the static elements on page load, so that you don't have to query for them every time you need them.)